# Java Servlet check if username already exist

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jaxb

This is a function which checks if username already exists  and then add it if is absent. It's in class DepartmentBean.

private List users;

```
public List<UserBean> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public int flag;

public int getFlag() {
    return flag;
}


public void setFlag(int flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}

public void addIfAbsent(UserBean userBean) {

            if (users.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getUsername().equals(userBean.getUsername()))) {
        setFlag(1);// flag to indicate that there is user with the same name

            } else {

                setFlag(2);
           users.add(userBean);// add the user

            }
        }
```

In the Servlet I check the flag like this:

```
    DepartmentBean dp = new DepartmentBean();
    UserBean user = new UserBean();//UserBean is class which store name and password
    DepartmentBean departmentBean = read();
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");


    user.setPassowrd(password);
    user.setUsername(userName);
    departmentBean.addIfAbsent(user);

         if(dp.flag == 2)//if flag is 2, their's no user with the same name, so write it
         {

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    write(departmentBean);//write to xml

         }
```

If this is out from the if braces is working and record is maken. But if I use this if, it doesnt and brings me to white page instead of index.jsp.

That's write and read functions in the Servlet:

```
public static DepartmentBean read() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(DepartmentBean.class, UserBean.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        return (DepartmentBean) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("1.xml")));
    }

    public static void write(DepartmentBean department) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(DepartmentBean.class, UserBean.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(department, new File("1.xml"));
    }
```

Comment: Why not have `addIfAbsent(...)` return a boolean and get rid of the magic `flag`?  But then why would the servlet write it if add...if...absent should have already handled it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using two DepartmentBean variables: one called "dp" and one called "departmentBean". You use the latter to check if already exists a user (so "departmentBean.flag" get modified) and the "dp" to check the flag's value (which has not being modified before in the code). I would suggest this:

```
DepartmentBean departmentBean = new DepartmentBean();
UserBean user = new UserBean();
String userName = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");


user.setPassowrd(password);
user.setUsername(userName);
departmentBean.addIfAbsent(user);

if(departmentBean.flag == 2)
{

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    write(departmentBean);//write to xml

}
```